# I have to determine which of the following define a metric on $\Bbb R \,\,$?

Tags: metric-spaces

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Determine which of the following define a metric on $\Bbb R$:
>
> 1. $d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$
> 2. $d(x,y)=|x-2y|+|2y-x|$
> 3. $d(x,y)=|x^2-y^2|$

**MY ATTEMPT:**

In each of the aforementioned cases, $d(x,y) \ge 0 $ and $d(x,y)=d(y,x).$ So, I have to check the triangle inequality.

For option 1, $$d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|} \implies d(x,y) \le \frac {|x-y|}{|x-y|}=1$$ and hence $d(x,y) =1 \le d(x,z)+d(z,y)=2.$ So, option 1 defines a metric on $\Bbb R$.

For option 2, I can not prove triangle inequality and I need help here.

For option 3, we see that
$$\begin{align*}
d(x,y)&=|x^2-y^2|\\\\
& =|(x^2-z^2)+(z^2-y^2)| \\\\
&\le |x^2-z^2|+|z^2-y^2|\\\\
&=d(x,z)+d(z,y)
\end{align*}$$ and so option 3 defines a metric on $\Bbb R$.

Am I right? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: There's another property required of a metric which you haven't mentioned and would be easier to check than the triangle inequality.

Comment: What property? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$.

Comment: O sure. I knew that but forgot to mention. So, option 2 does not define a metric.

Comment: Maybe there is a typo in (2), a more reasonable question is $|x-2y|+|2x-y|$. Still no good.

Comment: Well, then it is at least doubly not a metric, if not triply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2) $d(1,2)=6$ while $d(2,1)=0$, so it fails to be a metric on two accounts of the definition.

For 1) your proof is incorrect as clearly $d(x,y)$ does not have to be equal to $1$ for all $x,y$ (in fact, it's never equal to $1$). You need to show that $d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$, so knowing that $d(u,v)\le 1$ does not help at all. Try proving it in general: for any metric $d$ whatsoever, the function $\rho(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ is a metric.

For 3) your proof of the triangle inequality is correct but $d(1,-1)=0$, thus it is not a metric space.

Comment: Can you give some hints how to prove triangle inequality for $\rho(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

This is for the 1)
d(x,y)=$\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$

You need to prove the triangular inequality, i.e.

$\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}\le$$\frac{|x-z|}{1+|x-z|}$+$\frac{|z-y|}{1+|z-y|}$

we have $1+|x-y|\leq 1+|x-z|+|z-y|$

$1-\frac{1}{1+|x-y|}\leq$$1-\frac{1}{1+|x-z|+|z-y|}$

$\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}\leq$$\frac{|x-z|+|z-y|}{1+|x-z|+|z-y|}$

$\leq\frac{|x-z|}{1+|x-z|+|z-y|}$+$\frac{|z-y|}{1+|x-z|+|z-y|}$

$\leq\frac{|x-z|}{1+|x-z|}$+$\frac{|z-y|}{1+|z-y|}$

This way you show that 1) satisfies the triangular inequality apart from the other two conditions to be a metric.

2) is not a metric, because |x-2y|$\ne$|y-2x| always, look up why.